# Get index of last repeated string in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray with multiple repeated strings, I am trying to get last string index.

```
 NSMutableArray *arrWithRepeatedStrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"iOS",@"apple",@"iOS",@"apple",@"apple",@"iOS", nil];
```

here `iOS` and `apple` are the repeated strings in my array. I think it's possible and am on the way to it. Can anyone help me.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want the index of last string object or the index of last occurrence of that string object?

Comment: In the example, would you want 0 or 5?

Comment: @suthar stop this joking. Please read the topic at least!

Comment: last occurance of the string @Gandalf

Comment: @Codecracker - Please update your question as this small piece of information is leading to many doubts and wrong answers :)

Comment: Why do you need 5 and not 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the index of last occurrence of string by enumerating in the reverse direction. Use the code below. You can change the matching string to `@"iOS"` if you want it's index and not `@"apple"`.

```
NSMutableArray *arrWithRepeatedStrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"iOS",@"apple",@"iOS",@"apple",@"apple",@"iOS", nil];
NSInteger index = [arrWithRepeatedStrings indexOfObjectWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse passingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if([obj isEqualToString: @"apple"])
           return YES;
        else
            return NO;
    }];
```

Comment: This answer does seem to have nothing to do with the question how I understand it. It just finds the last instance of a given constant, here @"apple".

Comment: @Eiko - The question was bit confusing initially and the way i took it was that OP was trying to figure out the last occurrence of a particular object. Yes i didn't take into account that if an object is more that once in array or not, but that is implicitly covered in this approach as if you have an object more than once and you want the index of the extreme last of it then enumerating from back will give you that automatically.

Comment: Then it should be called "lastIndexOfObject" or something like that... but as it seems to have solved @Codecracker's problem...

Answer (score 2):

I understand the question that you want the index of the last object that is more than once in the array. This is quite different from what @Gandalf's solution does, so here's my take:

```
NSInteger index = [array indexOfObjectWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse
                                      passingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                          BOOL match = [arrWithRepeatedStrings indexOfObject:obj] != idx;
                                          if (match) *stop = YES;
                                          return match;
                                      }];
```